# Show that the function $f(x,y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at 0, but is not of class $C^1$ in any neighborhood of 0.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

The problem from Munkres' *Analysis on Manifold* is that

> Show that the function $f(x,y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at 0, but is not of class $C^1$ in any neighborhood of $0$.

---

My thought on the first part is that since $Df(0)= [0  0]$, $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

However, I have no idea of how to approach to the second part.

This was my initial thought :

---

Let $x=(x_1, x_2)\in\Bbb R^2$.

Then,

$D_1f(x) =\begin{cases}x_2&\text{ if }\quad x_1x_2 &> 0\\x_1&\text{ if }\quad x_1x_2&<0\end{cases}$

Therefore, $D_1f(x) =0\quad as \quad x \to 0$.

Since $D_1f(0) = 0$, this implies that $D_1f$ is continuous at $0$. Similar argument goes for $D_2f$.

---

Is this result wrong or compatible to what the problem requires?

And how can I prove that $f$ is not continuously differentiable in neighborhood of $0$?

Thanks!

Comment: Continuously differentiable? Hm? Check the meaning of $C^1$ in multivariable calculus and you should be able to solve the problem. "Since $(DF)(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$". Well, of course. But why is it that $(DF)(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your prove for differentiability is okay.

**Not $C^1$:**

Notice that $D_1 f$ does not exist at $(0,y)$ for any $y\ne 0$.

**Differentiable:**

The function $f$ is constant zero on the axes. Thus, the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are $0$. Hence, the candidate for $Df(0)$ is $(0,0)$.
Now, for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ we have
$$ \begin{align} 
|f(x,y) - f(0,0) - 0\cdot x - 0\cdot y| 
&= |x||y| \\
&= \min(|x|,|y|)\max(|x|,|y|)  \\
&\le \min(|x|,|y|) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.
\end{align}$$
As $\min(|x|,|y|)$ tends to $0$ for $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, we have shown that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with $Df(0,0) = (0,0)$.

Comment: Many thanks!! But I'm not sure why $D_1f$ is not continuous at (0,y)... Is it that $D_1f(0,y)$ doesn't exist? (since the limit from the negative direction and positive direction don't agree..) Or does it exist but not continuous? Thanks!

Comment: @user254703 right, $D_1 f(0, y)$ does not even exist for $y\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have a good day!

Comment: @user251257 How do you see it doesn't exist

Comment: @mavavilj can you show that $\mathbb R \ni t\mapsto |t|$ isn't differentiable at $0$?

Comment: how does that help expalin its not c1? can you explain the not c1 line a bit more?