# Show that the function $f(x, y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Firstly I understand that this question has already been asked : [Show that the function $f(x,y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at 0, but is not of class $C^1$ in any neighborhood of 0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361876/show-that-the-function-fx-y-xy-is-differentiable-at-0-but-is-not-of-cla) However that question did not address the question I'm about to ask.

---

In trying to show that $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x, y) = |xy|$ is differentaible at $(0, 0)$ I first calculated the directional derivatives at $(0, 0)$ and I got $D_1f(0, 0) =D_2f(0, 0) = 0$, thus if $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$ then we'd have $Df(0, 0) = [0 \ \ \ 0 ]$

Now I tried to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$ by using the definition and $Df(0, 0)$ above as a canditate matrix for the derivative (because if the limit doesn't tend to zero using this matrix then it won't exist) and I arrived at the following (letting $h = (c, d)$)

$$\lim_{h \to (0, 0)} \frac{f((0, 0) + h) - f(0, 0) - Df(0, 0) \cdot h}{|h|} = \lim_{(c, d) \to (0, 0)} \frac{|cd|}{\sqrt{c^2 + d^2}}$$ but from the above it's not clear (to me) that $$\lim_{(c, d) \to (0, 0)} \frac{|cd|}{\sqrt{c^2 + d^2}} = 0$$

so I can't conclude that $f(x, y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$ using the definition. Now there's one other way I think I can prove differentiability which is by using the following theorem

> *Theorem:* Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose that the partial derivatives of the component functions of $f$ exist at each point $x$ of $A$ and are continuous on $A$. Then $f$ is differentiable at each point of $A$.

So I tried to show then that $D_1f(x, y)$ existed and was continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, in attempting to show this I ended up with the following

$$D_1f(x, y) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f((x, y) + t(1, 0))-f(x, y)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{|(x+t)y|-|xy|}{t}$$
and again I'm not show how to evaluate this limit  so I can't make use of the above theorem.

---

Is there any other way to show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$? How could I show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\displaystyle\frac {|cd|} {\sqrt {c^{2}+d^{2}}} \leq \frac {c^{2}+d^{2}} {2\sqrt {c^{2}+d^{2}}} \to 0$.

Comment: What limit theorem are you using to claim this?

Comment: @Perturbative There's certainly a use of squeeze theorem here. The limit is squeezed between $0$ and $\frac{\|(c, d)\|}{2}$, both which tend to $0$.

Comment: If you're asking why the inequality, observe $ (c-d)^2\geq0 $ so that $ c^2-2cd+d^2\geq0 $, or $ (c^2+d^2)/2\geq cd $, whether $cd$ positive or negative. Thus $ (c^2+d^2)/2\geq|cd| $, from which $ (c^2+d^2)/(2\sqrt(c^2+d^2))=(1/2)\sqrt(c^2+d^2)\to0 $.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
\frac{|cd|}{\sqrt{c^2 + d^2}}\leq \frac{|cd|}{\sqrt{0+ d^2}}=|c|
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|x_k| \le \|x\|$, hence $|f(x)| \le \|x\|^2$.

Then $|f(x)-f(0) - 0. x| \le \|x\|^2$, hence $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with
derivative $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for $c\neq 0$, $d \neq 0$, (or, more compactly, $cd \neq 0$)
$$  \sqrt{c^2 + d^2} = |c| \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^2} + \frac{d^2}{c^2}} = |cd| \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^2d^2} + \frac{d^2}{c^2d^2}} = |cd| \sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2} + \frac{1}{d^2}}  \text{.}  $$

Then 
$$
\frac{|cd|}{\sqrt{c^2 + d^2}} = \begin{cases}
0, & cd = 0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2} + \frac{1}{d^2}}}, &cd \neq 0
\end{cases}  \text{,}
$$ both cases of which have limit $0$ as $(c,d) \rightarrow (0,0)$.