# Checking to use definition derivative on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

- Show that the function $f(x,y)=|xy|$ is differentiable at $0$, but is not of class $C^1$ in any neighborhood of $0$.

Note: I know that the question is answered on the website, I want to seee that did I use the definition rightly?

My Attempt. Let $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R^2}$.

If $xy\geq 0$

$$Df_1(x)=\dfrac{f(x_1+h,x_2)-f(x_1,x_2)-Bh} {|h|}$$

$$=\dfrac{|(x_1+h)x_2|-|x_1x_2|-0} {|h|}, \quad as \quad B=[0 0] $$

$$=\dfrac{|x_1x_2|+|x_2||h|-|x_1x_2|} {|h|}= $$

$$=\dfrac{|x_2||h|} {|h|}=x_2.$$

Similarly,

$$Df_2(x)=\dfrac{f(x_1, x_2+h)-f(x_1,x_2)-Bh} {|h|}=x_1$$

If $xy\leq 0$, then $Df_1(x)=-x_2$ and $Df_2(x)=-x_1$.

Thus, $Df_1(0)=0$ as $h$ $\to$ $0$, and $Df_2(0)=0$ as $h$ $\to$ $0$.

Now, let's check $f$ is not $C^1$ in any neighborhood of $0$.

Since $\lim_{(h_1,h_2)\to (0,y)}Df_1(0)=y$ and $\lim_{(h_1,h_2)\to (0,y)}Df_2(0)=0$ and $y\neq 0$, so $f$ is not continous at $(0,y)$ for any $y\neq 0$. Thus, $f$ is not $C^1$ in any neighborhood $0$.

**May you check my attempt? Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things -

1. Existence of partials does not imply differentiability
2. Its not clear to me why you know that $B = [0\quad 0]$. Is it even true for every $x$...
3. Your notation confuses me. In my experience, notation like $Df_1$ suggests that this is a kind of derivative, but you leave the limit outside. And the dependence on $h$ is left implicit. And then you write $\lim_{(h_1,h_2)\to (0,y)} D f_1(0)$, but in your definition of $Df_1(x)$, there is only one $h$?
4. You probably intended to write "so $\lim_{\text{something}\to 0}Df$ is not continuous"
5. It seems that you show that the $x$ partial is not the same as the $y$ partial. This doesn't imply that the function isn't continuously differentiable.

First you can compute partials $\partial_x f,\partial_y f$, to understand what the derivative should be(which, because I don't get your notation, I'll write as $df$).
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn} \partial_x f(x,y) = |y|\sgn x, \quad \partial_y f(x,y) = |x|\sgn y. $$
OK, so a reasonable guess for the derivative at $(0,0)$ [$\color{red}{\text{and not at every $x$}}]$ is $B\binom{h}{v} = 0$, or $B = [0\quad 0]$.
In order for this to be true, we need to check a certain limit [$\color{red}{\text{and}}$ $\color{red}{\text{not}}$ $\color{red}{\text{just}}$ $\color{red}{\text{those}}$ $\color{red}{\text{limits}}$ $\color{red}{\text{in}}$ $\color{red}{\text{those}}$ $\color{red}{\text{2}}$ $\color{red}{\text{directions}}]$.

$$ \frac{|f(h,v)-f(0,0) - B\binom{h}{v}|}{|(h,v)|} = \frac{|hv|-0-0}{|h^2 + v^2|^{1/2}} \overset{\Huge ?}{\xrightarrow[(h,v)\to 0]{}} 0$$

To finish, you should maybe expand the square in $0\le (a-b)^2$. This proves that indeed, $$df(0,0)(h,v) = (0,0).$$

Now to check that $f$ is not $C^1$, it is sufficient to check that one of the partials is not continuous [due to a theorem; which one?] [$\color{red}{\text{and we don't need to compare derivatives in different directions}}$]. Either of them will do, as the presence of the $\sgn$ term breaks continuity. You might start by choosing a small neighbourhood around $0$.

PS the post alluded to is presumably [Show that the function $f(x,y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at 0, but is not of class $C^1$ in any neighborhood of 0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361876/show-that-the-function-fx-y-xy-is-differentiable-at-0-but-is-not-of-cla?rq=1) , which has essentially the same solution.

---

Response to comments.

- $f$ is continuous. This is because $f$ is a product of continuous functions $|x|$ and $|y|$.
- $f$ is differentiable at $0$. This is what was proved above. The derivative is $[0\quad 0]$.
- $f$ is differentiable on the whole set $\{ x,y : xy \neq 0 \}$ which is $\mathbb R^2$ minus the two axes. (In fact, $f$ is $C^\infty$ smooth on this set.) This is because $|x|$ is smooth when you avoid $x=0$, and similarly with $|y|$. If the partials are $C^1$ functions on a set $U$, this implies differentiability on $U$ (in the sense of Munkres' book). This should be a theorem somewhere in the book. The derivative is given in components by the partials I computed above-
  $$ D f(x,y) = [|y|\sgn x\quad   |x|\sgn y]. $$
  as mentioned, these functions are infinitely differentiable on any open set where you avoid $xy=0$.
- $f$ is not differentiable on the lines $xy=0$, except at $(0,0)$ itself. Recall that if $f$ is differentiable, then its partial derivatives exist. On the $y$-axis, $\partial_x f$ doesn't exist, and on the $x$-axis, $\partial_y f$ doesn't exist. To see this for the $y$ axis, note that for fixed $y>0$, the function is
  $$ f(x,y) = |xy| = C|x|$$
  where $C$ is a constant depending on $y$. (actually $C = |y|$, but the only thing that matters is $C>0$.) You should already know that $|x|$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$, so the same is true for the original function $f$.

You don't need all that for the answer, of course. An answer could look like this:

1. Let $U$ be any open neighbourhood of $(0,0)$.
2. $U$ contains a ball around $(0,0)$, and therefore $U$ contains a horizontal line crossing the $y$-axis.
3. Along this line, we form the difference quotient
   $$\delta_h f(0,y) =  \frac{f(h,y) - f(0,y)}{h}$$
4. Show that $$\lim_{h\to 0+} \delta_h f(0,y)  \neq \lim_{h\to 0-} \delta_h f(0,y). $$ This implies that for any $B$,
   $$ \lim_{(h,v)\to 0} \frac{|f(h,y+v) - f(0,y) - B(h,v)|}{|(h,v)|}$$
   does not exist.
5. Conclude- to be $C^1$ on $U$, $f$ needs to be differentiable on all of $U$. But this isn't true, therefore...

This is the same way that you show $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$, so an alternative to $3,4$ would be to quote the result for $|x|$.

PS you could try to graph the function on https://www.math3d.org (type `abs(x*y)`).

Comment: Thanks for answer and comments, I understood!

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet glad to help!

Comment: To show $D_1f$ does not exist at $(0,y)$ for any $y\neq 0$, $\lim_{(x_1,x_2)\to (0,y)}D_1f(x_1,x_2)=\lim_{(x_1,x_2)\to (0,y)}x_2=y$. But I couldn't show that $D_1f$ does not exist at $(0,y)$ for any $y\neq 0$, can you help?

Comment: Definition. Let $A \subset R^{m},$ let $f: A \rightarrow R^{n}$. Suppose $A$ contains a
neighbohood of a. We say that $f$ is differentiable at a if there is an $n$ by
$m$ matrix $B$ such that
$$
\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{a})-B \cdot \mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}|} \rightarrow 0 \text { as } \mathbf{h} \rightarrow \mathbf{0} \text { . }
$$
The matrix $B$, which is unique, is called the derivative of $f$ at a; it is denoted
$D f(\mathbf{a}) .$ The definition is from Munkres' Analysis on Manifold

Comment: If I mean $D_1f(x)$, I say first partial is differentiable at $x$ to use above definition.

Comment: I'm confused, how can I how partial derivative exist, how can I show $f$ is continous or not continous at $x$, how can I show $f$ is derivative at $x$? May you give me these definition to show exist or not exist?

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet I'll edit the answer, give me a moment

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet I've edited the answer, hopefully it helps

Comment: Thanks.........