# Differentiable function Understanding a proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

> Show that the function $f(x,y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at 0, but is not of class $C^1$ in any neighborhood of 0.

I have seen the proof from here ([Show that the function $f(x,y) = |xy|$ is differentiable at 0, but is not of class $C^1$ in any neighborhood of 0.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361876/show-that-the-function-fx-y-xy-is-differentiable-at-0-but-is-not-of-cla))

"Let x = $(x_1, x_2)$$\in$$R^2$.

Then,

$D_1f(x) = x_2 \quad if \quad x_1x_2 > 0$

$\quad \quad$$         = -x_2 \quad if \quad x_1x_2<0$

Therefore, $D_1f(x) =0\quad as \quad x \to 0$.

Since $D_1f(0) = 0$, this implies that $D_1f$ is continuous at 0. Similar argument goes for $D_2f$.

Notice that 1 does not exist at (0,) for any ≠0."

*However, I do not understand the last statement; I understand the general concept of since D1f is an absolute value, it is not differentiable at point 0 like f=|x|, but I have a hard time translating the part "Notice that 1 does not exist at (0,) for any ≠0." into an actual rigorous argument. I just thought of if x2 is not 0, then D1f equals to what specifically?*

Answer (score 3):

By definition $$D_1f(x_1, x_2) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_1 + t, x_2) - f(x_1, x_2)}{t}$$

Let's compute $D_1f(0, x_2), \ x_2 \neq 0$:

$$D_1f(0, x_2) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0 + t, x_2) - f(0, x_2)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|tx_2|}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} |x_2| \cdot \frac{|t|}{t}, $$ and such limit doesn't exist. Thus $D_1 f$ does not exists in $(0, x_2)$, since  in any neighborhood $U$ of $(0, 0)$ there is  point $(0, x_2), \ x_2 \neq 0$ we conclude that $f$ is not $C^1$ in $U$, because $D_1 f$ doesn't exist in $(0, x_2)$.

Comment: $x_1$ should be $0.$

Comment: You're right, thank you.