# Derivatives of $\lvert xy\rvert$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Munkres's analysis on manifolds

> Show that the function $f(x,y)=\lvert xy\rvert$ is differentiable at $0$, but is not of class $\mathscr{C}^1$ in any neighborhood of $0$.

For nonzero $h=(h_1,h_2)$,
$$ \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{\lvert h\rvert}=\frac{\lvert h_1h_2\rvert}{\lvert h\rvert}\leq\lvert h_1\rvert\rightarrow 0$$
as $h\rightarrow 0$, so that $Df(0) is the zero transformation.

For $y>0$, $D_1f(x,y)=y$ if $x>0$, $D_1f(x,y)=-y$ if $x<0$, and $D_1f(0,y)=0$.
For $y<0$, $D_1f(x,y)=-y$ if $x>0$, $D_1f(x,y)=y$ if $x<0$, and $D_1f(0,y)=0$.
For $y=0$, $D_1f(x,y)=0$.

By interchanging $x$ and $y$, we obtain $D_2(x,y)$.

I don't see why $f$ is not in $\mathscr{C}^1$.

Comment: From the related questions to the right: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361876/show-that-the-function-fx-y-xy-is-differentiable-at-0-but-is-not-of-cla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your computation $D_1f(\frac 1 n ,y)=y$ and $D_1f(0,y)=0$ if $y >0$. Every neighborhood  of $(0,0)$ contains points with $y >0$ and $D_1f(\frac 1 n ,y)$ does not tend to $D_1f(0 ,y)$, so $D_1f$ is not continuous in the neighborhood.