# check the differentiability of $f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> For what values of $p$ the $f(x,y)=\vert xy \vert^p$ is differentiable at $(0,0)?$

My attempt:  clearly $(f_x)_{(0,0)}=0=(f_y)_{(0,0)}$,

Test for differentiability at the origin if,

$$\lim_{({h,k}) \to (0,0)} \frac {f(h,k)-f(0,0)-h(f_x)_{(0,0)}-k(f_y)_{(0,0)}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0
\\ \implies \lim_{({h,k}) \to (0,0)}\frac {\vert hk \vert ^p}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}----(*)$$

Now let $h=r\cos\theta$ and $k=r\sin\theta$ and $r=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$, then
$(*) $ equal to

$$=\lim_{r \to 0} r^{2p} \frac{\vert \cos\theta \sin\theta \vert^p} {r}
= \lim_{r \to 0}r^{2p-1}\vert  \frac{\sin2\theta}{2} \vert^p \leq \lim_{r \to 0}(r^{2p-1}/2^p) \leq \lim_{r \to 0}r^{2p-1} \leq \epsilon----(**)$$

**Edit:**
if $p=1$ then $(**)$ is $r \leq \epsilon =\delta$ which implies $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, also

limit in $(**)$ tends to zero only if
$2p-1\geq 1 \implies p \geq 1.$

Hence $f(x,y)$ is  differentiable if $p\geq 1.$

Please check Is my solution is correct or did I mistake somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to know Is my solution is correct or wrong in some steps so that I can rectify it. Please reply Thanks

Comment: For $p > 1$, you are correct. but the last part is poorly explained. "$\epsilon$" is meaningless if you just dump it in without explanation. A better explanation would be$$ 0 \le r^{2p-1}\left| \frac{\sin2\theta}{2} \right |^p \le r^{2p-1}$$ So $$ 0 \le \lim_{r\to 0} r^{2p-1}\left| \frac{\sin2\theta}{2} \right |^p \le \lim_{r\to 0} r^{2p-1} = 0$$ However, for $p = 1$ the rh limit is $\lim_{r \to 0} r^0 = 1$, so that argument fails, like it does for $p < 1$. "$r \le \epsilon = \delta$" is meaningless again. However this doesn't show $f$ isn't differentiable for $p\le 1$, so that's still needed.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for comment, I think for $p=1$ the function is also differentiable. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361876/show-that-the-function-fx-y-xy-is-differentiable-at-0-but-is-not-of-cla. But Not for $p<1.$ Right Sir.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with that, just pointing out that if you want to completely solve this you need a good demonstration of these. Without, you have not demonstrated that you have found all $p$ making $f$ differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

I give a simple solution to the above question as my above solution is not complete.

$f(x,y) $ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if  $$\lim_{({h,k}) \to (0,0)} \frac {f(h,k)-f(0,0)-h(f_x)_{(0,0)}-k(f_y)_{(0,0)}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

As posted in my above explanation,

$$\implies  \lim_{({h,k}) \to (0,0)}\frac {\vert hk \vert ^p}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0---(A)$$

we know,  $(h^2+k^2)^{1/2} \leq \sqrt 2 (hk)^{1/2}$ then $(A)$ becomes,

$$ \leq \lim_{({h,k}) \to (0,0)} {\vert hk \vert }^{p-1/2}=0 \iff p > 1/2$$

Hence $f(x,y)$ is differentiable if and only if $p >1/2.$